# Position submit button of the lightning:recordEditForm in the footer part of the modal window in slds

Tags: slds, lightning-recordeditform

Is it possible to position submit button of the `lightning:recordEditForm` in the footer part of the modal window in slds?

The problem is that the button should be between the `lightning:recordEditForm` tags, while position it in footer moves it out of the `lightning:recordEditForm`.

Button inside `lightning:recordEditForm`:

```
<section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01"
             aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-slide-up-saving">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <header class="slds-modal__header">
                <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">
                    {!v.headerText}
                </h2>
            </header>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">

                <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm"
                                          objectApiName="{!v.objectApiName}">
                    <lightning:messages />

                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.fields}" var="field">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="{!field}" />
                    </aura:iteration>

                    <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Create new" />
                </lightning:recordEditForm>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Button in footer attempt:

```
<section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01"
             aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-slide-up-saving">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <header class="slds-modal__header">
                <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">
                    {!v.headerText}
                </h2>
            </header>
            <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm"
                                      objectApiName="{!v.objectApiName}">

            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">


                    <lightning:messages />

                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.fields}" var="field">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="{!field}" />
                    </aura:iteration>

                    <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Create new" />


            </div>
                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Create new" />
                </footer>

            </lightning:recordEditForm>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Here is how I see it then:
[image]

Comment: Submit button doesn't have to be inside lightning:recordEditForm. You can put it outside and define JS function onlick. There you write component.find("auraIdOfForm").submit()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's put my answer here, so that it is visible for everyone interested.

Submit button doesn't have to be inside lightning:recordEditForm. You can put it outside and define JS function onlick. There you write component.find("auraIdOfForm").submit()